# Wanting to preserve duplicates when matching in R, while working with indices

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been working with the [zipcode](http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode/) package in R.

I am trying to look up some zipcodes I have in a vector.  This way, I can get longitude and latitude information that corresponds to my zipcodes (the zipcode package consists of a dataframe that has this information.)

Unfortunately, I'm getting an issue with duplicates.  Note that `myzips` has a duplicate.

```
data(zipcode)
myzips <- c(95125,94121,94121,94601, 94025)  
matchedzips <- zipcode[ zipcode$zip %in% myzips, ]
```

I get

```
        zip          city state latitude longitude
41275 94025    Menlo Park    CA 37.45169 -122.1839
41334 94121 San Francisco    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
41564 94601       Oakland    CA 37.77683 -122.2179
41756 95125      San Jose    CA 37.29509 -121.8965
```

which is great, but I really need

```
        zip          city state latitude longitude
41275 94025    Menlo Park    CA 37.45169 -122.1839
41334 94121 San Francisco    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
41334 94121 San Francisco    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
41564 94601       Oakland    CA 37.77683 -122.2179
41756 95125      San Jose    CA 37.29509 -121.8965
```

I'm surprised that this subsetting isn't working.  I fared no better with

```
matchedzips <- zipcode[ which(zipcode$zip %in% myzip)  , ].
```

How do I solve this particular problem, or more importantly, what is the mechanism at work here that is serving to ignore my duplicates?  Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: I believe this is because your duplicated zipcode in `myzip` occurs only once in `zipcode`

Answer (score 3):

Use `match` instead of `%in%`:

```
DF <- read.table(text='  zip          city state latitude longitude
41275 94025    "Menlo Park"    CA 37.45169 -122.1839
41334 94121 "San Francisco"    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
41564 94601       "Oakland"    CA 37.77683 -122.2179
41756 95125      "San Jose"    CA 37.29509 -121.8965', header=TRUE)

myzips <- c(95125,94121,94121,94601, 94025)  
DF[match(myzips, DF$zip), ]

#           zip          city state latitude longitude
# 41756   95125      San Jose    CA 37.29509 -121.8965
# 41334   94121 San Francisco    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
# 41334.1 94121 San Francisco    CA 37.77873 -122.4926
# 41564   94601       Oakland    CA 37.77683 -122.2179
# 41275   94025    Menlo Park    CA 37.45169 -122.1839
```

`zipcode$zip %in% myzips` means "all zipcode$zip which's values are in myzips". Since each value is in `zipcode$zip` only once it can be in the result only once.